# Find the year when the user will turn 100

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I moved to Python today after doing a little of c++. The following code works as intended, but I want to know if I should add the `if __name__ == "__main__"` statement. Any other improvements?

```
import datetime

def inputInfo() :
    userName = input("Who are you?")
    userAge = input("How old are you?")
    return (userName , userAge)

def findYearWhenAge100(name , age) :
    currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    currentYear = int(currentTime[0: 4])
    age = 100 - int(age)
    currentYear += age
    print( name ,"is going to be 100 by", currentYear)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userName , userAge = inputInfo()
    print(findYearWhenAge100(userName , userAge))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to the answers already here, four things jump out at me. The datetime calculations, the print statements, the import statement and the case used in variables.

**Case**: Python uses snake_case and not camelCase. Please look into formatting your code in a PEP8 way.

**import statement**: Your code only imports `datetime` and later, when you use it, you write `datetime.datetime.now()`. Here's a coding tip you might not have thought of previously - if you need to use more than a single period in your `objects.attributes` or `objects.methods()`, then you're probably importing too much/too high a level.
Of course, my example violates that as I request the attribute after the method call - (¬‿¬) but the point remains true for imports.

**Datetime**: Your code converts the datetime into a string, slices it, converts it to an integer. This is unnecessary. If you're going to perform calculations, leave everything as integers/floats.

**Strings**: Please look into the format function or if you use Python 3.6 or newer, f-strings. I'll put both in the example below including executing a function inside an f-string (so, 3 print statements).

```
from datetime import datetime


def get_user_input():
    name = input("Please tell me your name: ")
    age = int(input("How old are you?"))
    return name, age


def what_year_when_100(age):
    return 100 - age + datetime.now().year


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_name, user_age = get_user_input()
    print(f"{user_name} is going to be 100 by {what_year_when_100(user_age)}") # Python 3.6+
    when_100 = what_year_when_100(user_age)
    print("{} is going to be 100 by {}".format(user_name, when_100)) #Python 2/3
    print(f"{user_name} is going to be 100 by {when_100}") # Python 3.6+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think year_when_100 is explicit enough

Answer (score 6):

Your `findYearWhenAge100()` function has a `print()` statement, and returns nothing, so your `__main__` doesn’t need to print the return value.

---

A good habit is adding `"""docstrings"""`  to your functions.  Eg)

```
def inputInfo():
    """Asks the user for name and age"""
    #... remainder of code
```

---

The `userInput()` function should do things like turning the `userAge` string into an int.  That should not be the responsibility of functions which need the age.

---

Use `pylint`.  It will help you write more standardized code.  Things like a space is expected after a comma, not before.

Comment: True, I don't know why I did that. Thanks

Comment: After your first sentence I expected to read something like "make the function return the value so that it can be later printed outside the function". Functions such as `findYearWhenAge100` should be reserved for computation only. Input/Output should be managed somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Things like this can be confusing:

```
age = 100 - int(age)
currentYear += age
```

`age` *starts off* being the user's age, but then it gets changed to mean something different, and the name has become misleading.  Similarly for `currentYear`.  It may be better to introduce new variables, like this:

```
time_until_100 = 100 - int(age)
future_year = currentYear + time_until_100
```

Or to inline the calculation:

```
age = int(age)
print(name, "is going to be 100 by", currentYear - age + 100)
```

Or a compromise between the two

```
birth_year = currentYear - int(age)
print(name, "is going to be 100 by", birth_year + 100)
```

Perhaps this last one is clearest (though `birth_year` is only an estimate, given we don't know whether the user has had a birthday yet this year).